# Mapping ATC codes to names (Computational Pharmacology)

Tags: pharmacology

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anatomical_Therapeutic_Chemical_Classification_System):

> The Anatomical Therapeutic Chemical (ATC) Classification System is used for the classification of active ingredients of drugs according to the organ or system on which they act and their therapeutic, pharmacological and chemical properties. It is controlled by the World Health Organization Collaborating Centre for Drug Statistics Methodology (WHOCC)

The [WHOCC Website](https://www.whocc.no/atc_ddd_index/) has a manual search. But I'm looking for an automated way to map ATC Codes to their names. I'm currently interested in mapping third-level ATC codes. For example:

- `N03A` → ANTIEPILEPTICS
- `C03B` → LOW-CEILING DIURETICS, EXCL. THIAZIDES

In addition to third-level codes, an ideal solution would map codes of any level to their name. After lot's of Googling, I've yet to find a dataset (such as a JSON or TSV file) that contains both ATC codes and their names.

Fingers crossed I don't have to write a web scraper.

Comment: You can [download their database](https://www.whocc.no/atc_ddd_index_and_guidelines/order/) and parse your list. It seems to be not free (they take ~200 Euros). I would say that it is not really worth 200 euros. You can automate the search by appending the search term to the address `https://www.whocc.no/atc_ddd_index/?code=N03`. Anyway, this is not a biological question in a strict sense and would be put on hold.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about biology or bioinformatics.

Comment: Thanks @WYSIWYG—sorry I overlooked the Order page. I [wasn't expecting](https://twitter.com/dhimmel/status/818858574285832199) the United Nations to sell access to data that's part of essential biomedical infrastructure.

Answer (score 1):

After some more intense Googling, I found a TSV that did the job:

- [versioned blob link](https://github.com/OHDSI/Vocabulary-v4.5/blob/661804cf3c17add61b02e2e83e477f48acb011d5/21-ATC/atc_code.txt)

You can access the file as raw text with the URL `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/OHDSI/Vocabulary-v4.5/661804cf3c17add61b02e2e83e477f48acb011d5/21-ATC/atc_code.txt`.

Thanks [OMOP Standardized Vocabularies V4.5](https://github.com/OHDSI/Vocabulary-v4.5) for making this file available on GitHub!

This file was last updated on Aug 24, 2014 and is not actively maintained. It would be much more preferable if WHOCC hosted their datasets in a machine readable format. Furthermore, WHOCC should openly license to their content.

I'll keep this question open in case anyone knows of a better solution.